# Вывод текста в классе си++

Tags: c++, классы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести текст в классе.

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS  
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <math.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>

class massiv {
private:
    int kol;
    int min, max;
public:
    void set_kol(int n)
    {
        kol = n;
    }
    void vvod(float *arr, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            do {
                printf("a[%d] = ", i);
                std::cin >> arr[i];
                if (arr[i] < 100 && arr[i] > -100) break;
                else printf("Не двузначное \n");
            } while (1);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void set_min_max(int x1, int x2)
    {
        min = x1;
        max = x2;
    }

    void sredznach(float min, float max, float *arr, int n) {
        float  summ = 0, j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if ((min <= arr[i]) && (arr[i] <= max)) {
                j++;
                summ += arr[i];
            }
        }
        if (j != 0) std::cout<<"Cреднее значение: " << setw(2)<< (summ / j);

    }
    void maxium( float *arr, int n, float x1, float x2)
    {
        float maxx = -1e38;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arr[i] >= min && arr[i] <= max && maxx <= arr[i]) {
                maxx = arr[i];
            }

        }

        std::cout << maxx;
    }

};

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int i, n, x1, x2;
    system("cls");
    printf("Привет! Введи размер массива (не более 16): ");
    while (1) {
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n > 1 && n < 17) {
            printf("Число элементов массива = %d \n\n", n);
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Попробуй еще раз. Помни! Не больше 16 элементов: \t");
        }
    }

    massiv A;
    float *a;
    a = new float[n];
    A.set_kol(n);
    A.vvod(a, n);

    printf("Введи нижний порог интервала:");
    scanf("%f", &x1);
    printf("Введи верхний порог интервала:");
    scanf("%f", &x2);

    A.set_min_max(x1, x2);
    A.sredznach(x1, x2, a, n);

    A.maxium( a, n, x1, x2);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Где я допустила логическую ошибку, что в maxium выводится -1+38. А  `#include <iomanip>` не работает ( `setw()` мне нужен, чтобы вывести число в формате цц.цц)? И еще один вопрос: можно ли было запихнуть функцию, написанную вне класса, в любой метод класса или ее надо создавать только в классе?

Comment: библиотека  #include <iomanip>, странно, что она не отображается

Comment: ничего странного. Странно, что вы пишете кашу, а потом удивляетесь, что не получили порядок

Comment: std::setw(), так как using namespace std; объявлен после класса

Comment: спасибо! Может вы знаете как вывести значение из класса с помощью cout и в чем ошибка в определении максимума?

Comment: Что такое "не работает"? "можно ли было запихнуть функцию, написанную вне класса, в любой метод класса" - о чем именно здесь идет речь? И что за дикая смесь С и С++ ввода-вывода наблюдается в коде?

Answer (score 0):

1. В функции main x1, x2 являются типом int, а считывается в них float,и поэтому считывается в них ересь(потому и не ищется maximum).
2. Тебе нужен setprecision() а не setw()
3. Можно. Главное чтобы она или её прототип был описан до определения метода.